# where is `cc_proto_library` implementation in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I read the source code of [bazel](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel), and I found `cc_binary` and `cc_library` in `src/main/starlark/builtins_bzl/common/cc`.

Also I found `proto_library` in `src/main/starlark/builtins_bzl/common/proto`. But I can't find where is the `cc_proto_library`'s implementation.

Can anyone tell me how it works?

Comment: Here you can find it [cc_proto_library's](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/proto/CcProtoLibrary.java) and [documentation](https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_proto_library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip: use the Bazel codesearch at https://source.bazel.build to navigate its source code.

You can quickly find the implementation of any built-in rule using a query like:

```
language:java "implements RuleDefinition" "\"cc_proto_library\")"
```

This will bring you to the [CcProtoLibraryRule.java](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/proto/CcProtoLibraryRule.java;l=57;drc=9868455f017ddf00eaef02cb52551b45212d4136) definition:

```
public class CcProtoLibraryRule implements RuleDefinition {

  private final CcProtoAspect ccProtoAspect;

  public CcProtoLibraryRule(CcProtoAspect ccProtoAspect) {
    this.ccProtoAspect = ccProtoAspect;
  }

  @Override
  public RuleClass build(RuleClass.Builder builder, RuleDefinitionEnvironment environment) {
    return builder
        .requiresConfigurationFragments(CppConfiguration.class)
        /* <!-- #BLAZE_RULE(cc_proto_library).ATTRIBUTE(deps) -->
        The list of <a href="protocol-buffer.html#proto_library"><code>proto_library</code></a>
        rules to generate C++ code for.
        <!-- #END_BLAZE_RULE.ATTRIBUTE --> */
        .override(
            attr("deps", LABEL_LIST)
                .allowedRuleClasses("proto_library")
                .allowedFileTypes()
                .aspect(ccProtoAspect))
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public Metadata getMetadata() {
    return RuleDefinition.Metadata.builder()
        .name("cc_proto_library")
        .factoryClass(CcProtoLibrary.class)
        .ancestors(BaseRuleClasses.NativeActionCreatingRule.class)
        .build();
  }
}
```

The implementation is defined with [`.factoryClass(CcProtoLibrary.class)`](https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/cpp/proto/CcProtoLibrary.java;l=30;drc=ea8b99cf2a5914c67e4bd7651d83df98912bb1ed).

For the second part of your question, "builtins" are a Bazel-internal concept to transparently swap out the Java implementation of a Bazel rule to its Starlark equivalent, without needing to add any `load` statements in the BUILD file. This is necessary to migrate existing users to Starlark implementations without causing user impact.